# Installing outlet in electrical box with two sets of wires?

Tags: electrical

(apologies for possibly very newbie question)

I found this setup in an electrical box in my downstairs closet underneath my stairs. It has two sets of wires that seems to be connected serially. My testing shows that the red wire is always hot, and the black and white wires only have voltage *if* the stairs lights are on too. What does it mean?

I would like to install a wall outlet here, and IIUC the steps are rougly:

1. Turn off breaker (duh)
2. Add a new wire from the outlet to the red wires nuts so now there's 3 wires in the nut.
3. Do the same with the ground wire.
4. This part I'm not sure, where should the final wire of the outlet go to? Black or white? Does it matter?

[image: two sets of wires]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Black or white? Does it matter?

It matters **a lot**. You need to learn the basics before you start messing with electricity. While this particular situation looks pretty straightforward, it might not be. Reading up a whole bunch (e.g., a *lot* on this system, but a book explaining it all step by step would be a great idea) is key. But a few notes to get you started:

##### Wire Colors

Generally speaking in the US/Canada:

- Green, green/yellow or bare wires are *ground*
- White, sometimes gray, is *neutral*
- Everything else - red (very common), blue, pink, yellow, orange, etc. is *hot*

There are some exceptions and caveats:

- White can be hot is certain specific situations, such as a 240V circuit (using black and white as the two hot wires) or an old-style switch loop with white as the hot wire and black as the switched hot wire. In these cases, the white wire is supposed to be marked, typically with electrical tape, black or red or another "hot" color. But it isn't always marked, and sometimes it *was* marked and the marking fell off years ago.
- Cables (which you have in this box, and likely throughout your house) come in black/white/bare (referred to as "/2" - the ground doesn't count in the numbering) and black/red/white/bare ("/3"). In addition to marking white as black, red, etc. to indicate it is hot, sometimes other wires will be marked different colors to indicate *function*. Any color can be used for marking except green or white because those are always ground and neutral and can't be marked to get those functions.
- Individual wires in conduit can be a lot of different colors but can *never* change status by marking - i.e., in conduit if you have a white that you want to use as hot, you need to add/replace it with a different color wire, not simply mark it black.

##### Typical Receptacle and Switch Wiring

Note that from this point on, I will ignore grounds. Ground wires always get connected together and, if you have metal boxes, connected to the boxes.

There are  4 main wire *functions* in 120V/240V wiring:

- Hot - always "on"
- Switched Hot - "on" only when a switch (or combination of switches) is on
- Neutral - the other half of each circuit (except 240V-only, which has two hots). Not usually switched. Often found together in bunches (e.g., 4 cables into a box with 3 switches will typically have the 4 neutral white wires together in a wire nut). Every receptacle needs neutral, but generally only smart switches and timers need neutral - simple switches and most dimmers do not need neutral.
- Travelers - the pair of wires connecting 3-way (and 4-way) switches. There will normally be a third wire in the same cable (neutral or switched hot) as well.

Generally speaking, black is preferred for hot and red for switched hot, but there is no official rule, *and it sounds like yours may be reversed*. You need to figure out 100% for sure which wire is which. I would do that using a non-contact voltage tester and by removing the wire nuts and separating the wires. If you do that and turn the breaker back on, you should get only *one* wire showing as hot - this will be the incoming hot wire. The matching wire (the wire that was under the same wire nut) is the outgoing hot. The other colored wires are for switched hot and the white wires are neutral.

Add a pigtail (short piece of wire, black for hot, white for neutral) to the wire nut containing the hot wires. Add a pigtail to the neutral wires. Connect those wires to the hot and neutral connections on the receptacle, as well as a ground wire (because you don't have a metal box).

For the receptacle, look for one that has *screw to clamp*. This will be better quality (at a cost of $2 or $3 instead of $1) than a basic receptacle and let you wire straight in under a clamp/screw. Do not use the "back stab" connections (push wire in, no screw to tighten) because they are not as reliable.

Comment: > I would do that using a non-contact voltage tester and by removing the wire nuts and separating the wires.

I just tried it with a klein tools dual range voltage tester (ncvt-2) and found that:

1. The black wires are always off.
2. One of the red wires is always on.
3. One of the white wires is always on. 

I'm really not sure what to make of this...

Comment: Black should be added to the "everything else" wire color category. Also, it's worth watching some videos and practicing on scrap wire to get the hang of properly fully tightening wire nut connections. A loose one can "arc" (spark) and cause a fire.

Comment: If the white that is always on is in the same cable as the red always on then it is possibly neutral with induced/phantom voltage

Comment: Some clarification: Wire A's red and white is always hot. It seems the white is less sensitive than the red. Wire A's black is never hot. Wire B's red and white are never hot, and the black is hot when I turn on the light switch. However this black wire is also not as sensitive, I really had to touch down on it hard with the voltage tester to get the fast beep. I guess this means my red is hot and black is switched hot? But why is my white wire hot as well?

Comment: Yes, sounds like red hot, black switched hot, white neutral *induced/phantom* when off.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if that one black wire is affected by the light switch at all. I can not get a reliable hot indication when using the voltage tester on it. Sometimes it will indicate hot, but if I move it even slightly then not hot.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm beginning to understand what's going on. The picture shows two 12/3 connected together because each wire actually goes to a three way switch that powers the stairs light. I guess the reason why it meets here like this is becuase the two three way switches are on different floors.

My original intention was to see if I could install an always hot wall outlet at this location, but AFAIU that is not possible because of the three way wiring. There is no always hot wire in this box. I believe the solution is to use wireless switches, but I'll leave that for another day.

Thank you all for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

The black wire is a switch leg and doesn't need to be used unless you want the outlet controlled by the switch.  Make a pigtail for the hot/red, the neutral/white, and the ground/bare and splice them with the existing wires.  Tuck the black wires into the back of the box.  Just verify what circuit the red wires are on and ensure they aren't part of a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Based on additional information from the OP,  this doesn't answer the question.